# I am getting error in the console while trying to run my angular with npm run start-ssr

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I am trying to include angular Universal in my angular 7 app. I worked to the point of running with `npm run start-ssr`, but I am getting the below error in my node console.

***Cannot find name require. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try npm i @types/node` and then add node to the types field in your tsconfig***

and

***Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try npm i @types/node and then add node to the types field in your tsconfig***

and

***src/server.ts(26,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'global'***

I have in my app ***webpack.server.config.ts*** with the code

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: {
    server: './server.ts',
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      {
        // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
        // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
        test: /(\\|\/)@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/).+\.js$/,
        parser: { system: true },
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
}
```

In my ***tsconfig.json***

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed @types/node as it says in the error message? If not:

1. Run `npm i @types/node`
2. Then go to `./app/src/tsconfig.server.json`

   > `"compilerOptions": {
   >     "types": [
   >        "node"
   >     ]
   >   },`
3. Restart `npm run start-ssr` command.

Comment: Yes i did exactly just like that and the error still coming up

Comment: i have now fixed it by adding it to tsconfig.server.json too . not that error anymore .  But i am now having another issue again .  It is now complaining of not seeing my service i generated which is used by most of my components. i checked and found the service is still in my available

Comment: The service is way different problem. I would need more information to be able to help you, though I believe there should be a lot of answers already about services not being able to find to.